# Window Property Not Getting in Page Level

Tags: wpf-controls

```
 <Grid>
    <Button Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Width="100"/>
    <Frame>
        <Frame.Content>
            <Page>
                <Button Content="{Binding Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Height="50" Width="100"/>
            </Page>
        </Frame.Content>
    </Frame>
    </Grid>
```

I am trying to bind Window Title Property Inside Page Button it is not Working but inside Window it is Properly Working.

Here is my  Xaml code:

[image]

Comment: Hello @joby james,.. i am facing similar situation of yours. did you solve this problem? if yes can you please post the solution. it will be really helpful for others. Thanks

Comment: Create one Dependency Property property in Page and Bind With that property first then Bind with that Page Button Property.